# How do i change my text .txt file to a .ora

Tags: tnsnames

So I tried to use tnsnames.ora in oracle, but it will not recognize my file and has a blank network alias while creating a tns connection. I found out that the file type is not correct.
My VScode and sublime text do not give me the options to save a oracle file.

Comment: A file's extension is just part of the name. Most editors have pre-defined extensions you can save the file with, but if you choose All Files (at the top of VS Code) you can put whatever extension you want in the filename. Or you could always rename the file afterwards using the command line or a file explorer.